# Looping external variable - collecting results

Tags: python

I want to loop through a list of variable values, pass these to the extrenal script and collect the result of the external script operation. My goal is to see how the objective result behaves in response to different values of a parameter

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import winsound
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statistics import stdev
from pandas import DataFrame


value_to_test=range(10,20)
values_list=list(value_to_test)
objective=0
parameter=1

for i in values_list:
    parameter=i/10    
    runfile('C:/Users/AGL/systems/Systems/trade_functions.py', wdir='C:/Users/AGL/systems/Systems')
    runfile('C:/Users/AGL/systems/Systems/system.py', wdir='C:/Users/AGL/systems/Systems')
    print(parameter,objective)
```

the system.py external script calculates the model based on the parameter values. initialy this parameter was imported from trade_functions.py as a static float value. Now I want to loop through a list of parameter values - 1 t- 2 in steps of 0.1. but for some reason python fails to pass the parameter value to the external script (system.py) each time the loop is calculated....
I get same objective outpu at each loop step:

```
1.0 1
1.1 1
1.2 1
1.3 1
1.4 1
1.5 1
1.6 1
1.7 1
1.8 1
1.9 1
```

Comment: Are the external scripts part of the project? Did you create them?

Comment: hi yes....initially this parameter was defined in trade_functions.py now I wante to lop through this parameter, set each time it in this code and pass it to system.py for evaluation

Answer (score 0):

If you own these external scripts, you might proceed another way: your scripts should be external modules that consists of functions that you could import to run them directly from your main script.

Let me try to illustrate this with an example.
In your folder, you could have to separate files : `main-file.py` and `trade_functions.py`. The second one would be your external scripts:

```py
def my_first_function(param1, param2):
    # (enter code here)
    return result1

def my_first_function(param1, param3):
    # (enter code here)
    return result2
```

Then, in your main code, you would import both functions and launch them directly:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import winsound
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statistics import stdev
from pandas import DataFrame

from trade_functions import function1, function2


value_to_test=range(10,20)
values_list=list(value_to_test)
objective=0
parameter=1

for i in values_list:
    parameter=i/10    
    # I do not know your functions, so these ar simple examples
    # The point is that you can use any parameter as you need
    res1 = function1(i, parameter)
    res2 = function2(i, objective)
    print(parameter,objective)
```

Comment: thank you for your kidn reply. but the fact is my main system.py script contant a lot of different calucations performed in a loop on multiple csv files - so canot call seperate functions from it....I just need to be abel to somehow pass the parameter values to the external script...I am currently trygn to operate on system.py directly - just looping throgh the parameters form there....do you know any good genetic algo optimiser for python which can scan optimal paramers?

Comment: Maybe try to reorg your code and use one or several external modules for your calculations to make the global code easier to understand... and maintain